# datetime data type to a date data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime

I am trying to convert the date time column of this format `1978-01-29 00:00:00.000` to date `1978-01-29`

I tried convert , cast, case statement ,nothing works. I am getting the following error

> The conversion of a date data type to a datetime data type resulted in
>   an out-of-range value.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I can't reproduce your error. Could you edit your post to include the code that failed, and the error message it produces?

Answer (score 1):

When I run:

```
SELECT CAST('1978-01-29 00:00:00.000' AS date)
```

I get:

```
1978-01-29
```

If you get an error running that exact code, then probably your locale settings are treating "29" as the month instead of the day, though I'm not aware of any locale setting that would treat that string that way.

I also just noticed that your error message says the error occurred while converting a `date` to a `datetime`.  Yet in your question you claim you are attempting to convert a "date time column" to a "date".   Maybe the error isn't in the part of the code you think it is.